# Idea on implementing the following pop up menu in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to have pop up menu, when I click on the 3 dots area in a `ListView` row.

[image]

[`registerForContextMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) won't meet my need, as it happen during long press, in any area of `ListView` row.

I would like to know.

1. How to create a 3 dots looking UI in `ListView` row?
2. How to have PopupMenu, even for Android 2.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use `ImageView` to display image with 3 dots.
2. There are two ways for popupmenu

   a) Use some layouts and make them visible/gone

   b) Use `PopupWindow`.

here is sample code for PopupWindow

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(context);

View popUpView = View.inflate(activity, linearlayout, null);
popUpView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mpopup.setContentView(popUpView);
mpopup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mpopup.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mpopup.setFocusable(true);
mpopup.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transperent));
mpopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
mpopup.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.slide_out_up);
mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.TOP, activity.getResources()
            .getInteger(R.integer.log_out_popup_x), activity.getResources()
            .getInteger(R.integer.log_out_popup_y));
```

Comment: how do you set the position of floating menu to appear just below 3 dots? And how to show it with fadein animation like play google?

Comment: @MustafaGüven you can find location of view (3 dots) suing `View.getLocationOnScreen()` and then set layoutparams to popup window.

Comment: what is mpopup and the linearlayout here?

Answer (score 2):

I know its a bit late and you probably may have found a solution but i just came across your question and here's my solution...

Below is my code of the getView method of the Adapter class...

```
@Override
public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.d_item, null);

        holder.dHeading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.ds = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        holder.options = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dPopupMenu);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.dHeading.setText(DList.get(p).getDHeading());
    holder.ds.setText(DList.get(p).getDs());

    holder.options.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final PopupMenu popmenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.options);
            popmenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dua_popup_menu, popmenu.getMenu());

            popmenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
            {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popmenu.show();
         }
     });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: how can we reduce the width and height of the pop menu,menu items are too big.@Abdul Rahman

Answer (score 0):

Or you can show a dialog, when 3 dots clicked.
PopupWindow need to locate where to show on the screen.
Show a dialog can indentify witch cloumn you selected.